# Log4net svc webservice doesn't log in release mode but works in debug (localhost)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-services, log4net

I have a .net application with log4net logger and if I run it in Debug (endpoint localhost) the client and the webservice log but if I run it on Release (endpoint being my website) the client still logs but the webservice doesn't.

I am sorry if this has been asked but I've been looking for the answer for about 7 hours.

This app was created 9 years ago and I changed it's target framework to 4.5.2 from 3.something.

I got an almost identical web.config to another app (recently created) and it works fine so I don't think that there's the problem (since it works on debug).

Yes I have the XmlConfigurator.Configure(); in my code and every solution you find on the first 2 pages of google.

I feel like I am missing something, maybe I even look at the solution but couldn't understand.

I'd rather not post the .config files but if I must to I will. Please help me find the bug.

**Debug.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###">
      <section name="###.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
      <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
               type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
           type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <appSettings>
    <!--Connections-->
    <add key="ORACLEConnection" value="###"/>
    <add key="USICOALConnection" value="###"/>
    <add key="CloseAfterSecs" value="43200"/>
    <add key="IsTest" value="True" />
    <add key="TestDbGroupName" value="###"/>

  </appSettings>
  <applicationSettings>
    <###.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="###" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://###.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </###.Properties.Settings>

    <log4net>
      <appender name="#####LogAppender"
                type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
        <file value="\\##\##\" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />

        <datepattern value="'log_'yyyyMMdd'_debug.txt'" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <converter>
            <name value="machine" />
            <type value="###.Services.MachinePatternConverter" />
          </converter>
          <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%machine] [%property{EmployeeNumber}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter" >
          <levelMin value="INFO" />
          <levelMax value="FATAL" />
        </filter>
      </appender>
      <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="#####LogAppender" />
      </root>
    </log4net>

  </applicationSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_#####" allowCookies="true"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/##################.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_#####"
                contract="#####WS.#####" name="BasicHttpBinding_###" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

**Release.config**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name="#####.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
          <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
          <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
                   type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
          <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
          <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
               type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="###" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0"/>
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
          <dataSources>
            <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
          </dataSources>
        </version>
      </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ORACLEConnection" value="##"/>
        <add key="USICOALConnection" value="##"/>
        <add key="CloseAfterSecs" value="43200"/>
        <add key="IsTest" value="False" />
        <add key="TestDbGroupName" value="HO-IT Support"/>
      </appSettings>
      <applicationSettings>
        <#####.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="#####_ClientSessionWS_ClientSessionWebService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://###.asmx</value>
          </setting>
        </#####.Properties.Settings>

        <log4net>
          <appender name="#####LogAppender"
                    type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
            <file value="\\##\##\"/>
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />

            <datepattern value="'log_'yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />

            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
              <converter>
                <name value="machine" />
                <type value="#####.Services.MachinePatternConverter" />
              </converter>
              <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%machine] [%property{EmployeeNumber}] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter" >
              <levelMin value="INFO" />
              <levelMax value="FATAL" />
            </filter>
          </appender>
          <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="#####LogAppender" />
          </root>
        </log4net>

      </applicationSettings>

      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
      </startup>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_#####Service" allowCookies="true"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                     maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                     sendTimeout="00:05:00">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000"
                            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://###/#####WS/#####.svc"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_#####Service"
                    contract="#####WS.#####Service" name="BasicHttpBinding_#####Service" />
        </client>

        <behaviors>

          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>

          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>

        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>

    </configuration>
```

**Web.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="#####LogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <file value="\\##\##\" /> 
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="15" />

      <datepattern value="'log_'yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{log4net:HostName}] [%property{EmployeeNumber}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter" >
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="#####LogAppender" />
    </root>

  </log4net>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel> 
    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>

        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.122.1.0" newVersion="4.122.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: think  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed to understand problem. Without sample it is not clear what it could be

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I'll post tomorrow debug, release and web configs

Comment: @tym32167 can you please have a look now?

Comment: by mvce I meant something which I can download, run and repro your issue. Moreover, you said that configs should be fine (i se only couple of differences like ```IsTest``` key and endpoint address). So, this not much helps. But are you sure that in release config your service is running, not crashed?

Comment: Yes, all my procedures get called and the app works fine, the only thing that doesn't work is logging. I am using the same webservice for another application and that one logs from the ws but this one does not..

Comment: So, you can run it in release mode with debugger and check which loggers are configured runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission problem. This app was logging only from the client in before to a folder and the webservice didn't have write permission on that folder.

Changing the target folder solved my problem.

Thank you @tym32167 for your interest in my problem.